# Printing list like a special structure

Tags: python, list, printing

I have something like this :

```
list = [{'nom': 'Wanda Maximoff', 'crimes': ['A conspiré avec Ultron', 'A agressé Vision', "A détruit l'aéroport de Vienne"], 'univers': 'Marvel', 'ID': 501988, 'danger': 45}]
```

and i need that this list printed in the output like this:

```
- Wanda Maximoff, ID 501988, univers Marvel
     Niveau de danger : 45
     Crimes commis :
         - A conspiré avec Ultron
         - A agressé Vision
         - A détruit l'aéroport de Vienne
```

I can also have another character inside my list.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is your question for us? This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what the problem is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own print function which will print the record following the format you want:

```
def printRecords(records):
    for record in records:
        print("- " + record['nom'] + ", ID " + str(record['ID']) + ", univers " + record['univers'])
        print("\tNiveau de danger : " + str(record['danger']))
        print("\tCrimes commis : ")
        for crime in record['crimes']:
            print("\t\t- " + crime)

inlist = [{'nom': 'Wanda Maximoff', 'crimes': ['A conspiré avec Ultron', 'A agressé Vision', "A détruit l'aéroport de Vienne"], 'univers': 'Marvel', 'ID': 501988, 'danger': 45}]
printRecords(inlist)
```

**Note**: Do not use `list` as variable name as it is a reserved keyword by Python. Consider using a different name.